# Beginner Java OOP

Tags: java, class, oop, tostring

I am developing a simple Dog class to create dog objects and display the results.

```
Dog
_________

int - size
String - breed;
String - name;

__________

Dog(int, String, String)
bark()
bark(int)
toString(): String
print()
```

I have made the class successfully using getters and setters but my problem is the toString and print methods. I understand the toString method should return a string with the dog details but don't know how to print them.

I could in theory print it like this:

```
Dog a = new Dog ();
String details = a.toString();
System.out.println(details);
```

But this isn't how it's specified in the UML spec.

Should the toString method call the print method itself?
and if so, how?

Dog class:

```
class Dog{
    private int size;
    private String breed;
    private String name;


    //Create getter and setter methods:
    public void setName (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSize (int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setBreed (String breed){
        this.breed = breed;
    } 

    public int getSize () {
        return this.size;
    }

    public String getBreed () {
        return this.breed;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void bark () {
        System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
    }

    public void bark (int amtOfBarks){
        for (int i = 0; i < amtOfBarks; i++){
        System.out.print("Ruff! Ruff! ");
        }
    }


     public String toString () {
        return "Name: "+this.name+"\nBreed: "+this.breed+"\nSize: "+this.size;
    }



}
```

Main Method:

```
class TestDog {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Dog rex = new Dog();
        rex.setName("Rex");
        rex.setBreed("poodle");
        rex.setSize(1);

        rex.toString();



        rex.bark(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toString() method should not call the print() method. It should be the other way around.
Override toString() and call it from the print() method.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "details";
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println(this.toString()); // same as System.out.println(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your Class structure diagram, the `print()` method should call `System.out.println(this);`.

Note : The `toString()` will be called implicitly. in `System.out.println`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with klemenp.

write your toString() method as follows:

```
@override
public String toString () {
        return "Name: "+this.name+"\nBreed: "+this.breed+"\nSize: "+this.size;
    }
```

and it will be implicitly called when you print the Object:

Edit to your code :

```
class TestDog {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Dog rex = new Dog();
        rex.setName("Rex");
        rex.setBreed("poodle");
        rex.setSize(1);

        //rex.toString();

System.out.println(rex);

        rex.bark(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in class Dog

```
public String toString(){
    return "details of dog";
}
```

so you can:

```
a = new Dog();
```

....
    System.out.println(a);

Answer (score 0):

from the doc of [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

so to show your own details you have to override this method. a casual example is given here

```
public String toString(){
    String s = /// add your detials 
    return s;
}
```

now from the code where you are using dog instance print `dog.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dog in this case is :

Dog a = new Dog (120, "breedname", "name");

In order to print the details you need getters,

in a create a get function like

> getBreed(){
>       return breed; }

in dog, then to print you use:

System.out.println(a.getBreed());

Answer (score 0):

in Class Dog write toString() as follows :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "String describing the details about Dog class";
}
```

Here @Override annotation is required, because every class has Default toString() method inherited from Object class....

Comment: The `@Override` is not required, but it is good practice to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To represent your object as String you have to override **toString()** method.

It is usually done as below (Eclipse as an example can generate it for you, using fields you will tell)

```
class Dog {

    private int size;
    private String breed;
    private String name;

    //constructors, methods, getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [size=" + size + ", breed=" + breed + ", name=" + name
            + "]";
    }

}
```

Then you may use your instance object directly in System.out.println() and you will get String representation. You do NOT need to do as you said *String details = a.toString();* and only then use it.

```
    Dog dogInstance = new Dog(21, "Dog Breed", "Dog Name");
    System.out.println(dogInstance);
```

As a result will be:

```
Dog [size=21, breed=Dog Breed, name=Dog Name]
```